# I'd like to reuse code from another module in my Nodejs backend

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the Yeoman Generator Angular Fullstack and I'd like to reuse JS code from different directories within my server directory.  I'm referencing the file that has the functions I want like:

```
var something = require('/.path');
```

I get the error: *"Cannot find module"* in my terminal.

I tried a number of variations of the path working through all of the levels from server level down to file level where the given functions are contained.  I looked at a few tutorials:

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/
AND
https://www.launchacademy.com/codecabulary/learn-javascript/node/modules

I clearly missed something.  Each module of my nodejs has a controller with an `exports.create` function.  All of my code for each module is contained within my `exports.create` function accept for other required modules.  I have no problem requiring underscore or other libraries in my Node/Bower modules by the way.

To be as detailed as can be, I expected

```
var something = require('./directory/directory.controller.js');
```

Comment: What's the exact string you `require`d, and what is the full path to both files?

Comment: both? what do you mean?
server/api/wantToRequire/wantToRequire.controller.js and I want to do it from server/api/currentLocation/currentLocation.controller.js I requried: var something = require('./wantToRequire/wantToRequire.controller.js')

Comment: It's relative to the module doing the requiring `require('../wantToRequire/wantToRequire.controller.js')`

Comment: @rashadb: You need to pass a relative path.

Comment: Thanks! I just learned 'relative path'. Then what is a single . for?

Comment: single . references the same folder the module is in.

Comment: Maybe I should start another question or maybe it can be answered here, but I'm now getting undefined is not a function when I call it something.function(); where something is what I called the required file and function is the name of the function within exports.create in the required controller.

Comment: if you really named it `exports.create`, you would need `something.create.functionname`. Not sure where you got `create` from.

Comment: I just tried something.create.function() and I still get the undefined is not a function error. exports.create is the convention Angular Fullstack uses; I just went along with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var something = require('/.path');
```

The path you are using is likely incorrect. Probably you want to open the file called `path.js` contained in the same folder of the file from which you are importing it. In order to do that, you should change the import as follows :

```
var something = require('./path');
```

`./path` is a relative path where `.` stands for current directory.

`/.path` is an absolute path. In this case require is importing a *hidden* file in the root directory. I guess is not what you want.